# Can't find file in Development Web App converted to Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jax-rs

I have a Development Web App project that I converted to Maven project called TestServer2 and basically I have two files called pubKey.txt and smKey.txt as the image below.

[image: Details project]

I created a method that will collect the key file when the method was called with JAX-RS but it gave me error java.io.FileNotFoundException: key\smKey.txt (The system cannot find the path specified). Below is the code for the method:

```
package com.heyho.rest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import trabe.AbePrivateKey;
import trabe.AbeSecretMasterKey;
import trabe.Cpabe;
import trabe.policyparser.ParseException;

@Path("/service")
public class JSONService {


    @POST
    @Path("/userkey")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response createEncryptedKey(UserInput input) {

        File key = new File("key/smKey.txt");
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        byte[] encryptedSecret = null;
        byte[] privateKeyByte = null;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            AbeSecretMasterKey secretKey = AbeSecretMasterKey.readFromFile(key);
            secretKey.counter=input.getCounter();
            AbePrivateKey privateKey = Cpabe.keygenSingle(secretKey, input.getAttribute());
            privateKeyByte = privateKey.getAsByteArray();
            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey pubKey = factory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(input.getPublicKey()));
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            encryptedSecret = Encryption.blockCipher(privateKeyByte, 1, cipher);

        } catch (IOException | ParseException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        result.put("encryptedKey", encryptedSecret.toString());
        result.put("keyHash", Encryption.generateHash(privateKeyByte));
        String jsonResult = gson.toJson(result);

        return Response.status(201).entity(jsonResult).build();
    }

}
```

The file is there obviously but it couldn't find the path that I gave. Also the key folder is not compiled together into war file. Is there something wrong?

Comment: You can't depend on a file path when you deploy a Java EE application.  The way to do it is to read that resource as stream from the classpath.  Add that resource to your WEB-INF/classes folder in the WAR - that's in the classpath.

Comment: @duffymo On my eclipse I couldn'T find folder classes inside WEB-INF so instead I only put the key inside WEB-INF folder. Is that correct?

Comment: No.  Sounds like Eclipse didn't create a correct WAR file.  You must have WEB-INF/classes; that's where your compiled .class files go.

Comment: @duffymo In the WAR file there is classes folder I checked it already but how can I make sure that the key folder is included into classes folder when it is compiled?

Comment: You have to ask Eclipse to set up the WAR file for you before you deploy.  I use IntelliJ; I'm not much help with Eclipse details.  Tell it to move that key directory under WEB-INF/classes when it creates the WAR.